# Is there a way to enable React warnings in production build (NextJs app)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build

By default, React warnings are not shown in the production build.

> By default, React includes many helpful warnings. These warnings are very useful in development. However, they make React larger and slower so you should make sure to use the production version when you deploy the app.

This is included in the old documentation. I didn't find anything warning-related in the new one though.

I want to check for an issue that occurs only in the prod environment for some reason (probably env config, but anyway) and I'd like to see these warning messages in the browser console.